# Error: Cannot find nvCVImage DLL or its dependencies

Tags: c, cmake, dll, sdk, nvidia

Im trying to use Maxine, the Nvidia sdk (the one for the upscaling) i compiled everything i needed and gives me this error: `Error: Cannot find nvCVImage DLL or its dependencies`

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the Nvidia Broadcast SDK first.
Here is a link where you can download the SDK:
https://www.nvidia.com/de-at/geforce/broadcasting/broadcast-sdk/resources/

Hope this helped!